# Displaying a custom UIView in a storyboard

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, subclass

I found this custom UIView [here](https://gist.github.com/conorgriffin/431c752583df6221afc2)

Now, I want to add it to myViewController.
What I did:

In myViewController.h I have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CJGGridView.h"
@class CJGGridView;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet CJGGridView * theBoard;
@end
```

On the storyboard, I placed a UIView and defined it as a custom class "CJGridView"
I then connected it to "theBoard". In order to easily distinguish the View, I gave it an orange background color.

in myViewController.m I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    theBoard = [[CJGGridView alloc]initWithSquareSize:self.theBoard.frame.size.width/8];
}
```

Now, when I run the app, I do see an orange square, with some kind of gradient in the left upper corner.

However, I'm NOT seeing the grid that I expect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: u have iboutlet theBoard and using alloc init

Comment: Thanks! Changed it to:
theBoard = [theBoard initWithSquareSize:self.theBoard.frame.size.width/8];

Comment: Well, your answer is ambiguous. The solution is to init the IBOutlet. I already had the right class selected, as indicated in the question.
So, if you take that part out, I will tick you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u directly init in viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    theBoard = [CJGGridView initWithSquareSize:self.theBoard.frame.size.width/8];
}
```